# nextjs links without strings

Tags: next.js, next-router

Im new to nextjs, and Im checking if it will be good for the app that will have pretty complex and messy internal navigation. Just checked their documentation and I see that they recommend usage
of `Link` component like this  `<Link href="/your_path">Path</Link>`. A bit scary is that I have to provide 'your_path' as a string so every time i change page file name I have to manually update code that redirects to this page.  Is there any solution that allows me to define routing on my own so I can write something like (pseudocode)

```
routes = [
...
{
   page : 'page_name', 
   path : 'path_to_page'
}
...
]
```

So instead of using string I can do  `<Link href="{route.path}">Path</Link>` or Im condemned to use this file-system based router with all consequences?

Comment: Next uses file based routing... You can specify dynamic routes as well. https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes!

When you want to change a user route in NextJs you have 2 options,
The first is with the `<Link>` Element that you can specify a `href` to where it directs.

And you also have a `useRouter` hook for more complex routing for example if the user does an action that requires moving him into a different route you can do it internally in your handlers.
[For more information about useRouter hook](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router).

What I usually do is storing my routes in an object

```js
const ROUTES = {
  HOME: "/",
  ABOUT: "/about"
}
```

and wherever you call routes you just use the object so F.E

With Link tag

```js
<Link href={ROUTES.ABOUT}>ABOUT PAGE</Link>`
```

with useRouter hook

```js
// Inside a React Component
const router = useRouter();

const handleNavigateToAbout = () => {
  router.push(ROUTES.ABOUT);
}

return (
// SOME JSX
<button onClick={handleNavigateToAbout}> Go to about page! </button>
)
```